# Youtube API - exclude video from search (query)

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm getting a list of videos using Ajax, via a PHP client (something like the basic code provided by Google (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#search_by_keyword).

It works fine, but now, I want to exclude some videos from the query to the API : as I can retrieve (for example) 50 results, **I need to get 50 results excluding some videos ID** I already have.

*For the moment, I check it client-side (with JS), but as you can expect, I get 50 (- the number of videos I exclude with JS) results...*

My PHP call to the API :

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['query'],
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxNb'],
));
```

**Is there a param where I can put an array of videos ID to exclude ?**

Comment: I don't think there is an exclude method in the API but you can remove unwanted videos from the Response using PHP

Comment: But if I remove unwanted videos from the response, the problem will be the same : I will have (i.e) 50 results - unwanted videos ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to exclude some videos but you still want get the same number of results, as far as i know there is no parameter for excluding some videos in the Youtube API, but you can exclude them using PHP.

for example

```
// unwanted videos 
$excludedVideos = ['h2Nq0qv0K8M','_jKylhJtPmI','55GkIZOCeM8','_A3I9RDR6GA'];
```

now you should get the videos + the number of excluded videos

```
 $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
  'q' => $_GET['q'],
  // get your results + the number of unwanted videos
  'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'] + count($excludedVideos),
));
```

remove unwanted videos from the results

```
 // remove unwanted videos
foreach($searchResponse['items'] as $key => $item){
     if(in_array($item->id->videoId, $excludedVideos)){
          unset($searchResponse[$key]);
     }
}
```

Now it's time to display the results, you can't guarantee that all the number of `$excludedVideos` will be shown in the results so you need to limit  the results by `$_GET['maxResults']`

```
 $limit = 1;
 foreach ($searchResponse['items'] as $searchResult) {
      if($limit == $_GET['maxResults']) break;
      // do what ever you want with the results here
      $limit++; 
 }
```

This is just an example to give you an idea, you can change the code depending on your requirements.

Comment: I never thought about this, but this is pretty clever, thank you ! The only limit I see is when you when $_GET['maxResults'] + count($excludedVideos) > 50 (as it's the maximum of this param), any idea about that ?

Comment: Coming in late to this but YouTube sets the max limit to 50 results. For my use case I may have 30 videos I don't want to get so removing those only leaves 20 results. Not seeing any way around that so far. Will update here if I find something.